# How do I test if a boolean is changed?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a function in my ts file that changes the value of a boolean, but doesn't return a value. I can't figure out how I test this function in the spec.ts file.

This is the function in the ts file:

```
doesUserExist(username: string) {
  this.data.getUser(username).subscribe(data => {
    this.searchedUserExists = true;
  }, err => {
    this.searchedUserExists = false;
  });
}
```

This is what I have tried in the spec.ts file:

```
it('testIfUserExistsIsFalse', () => {
  let searchedUserExists: boolean;
  service.doesUserExist('falsegithubusername123');
  expect(searchedUserExists).toBeFalsy();
});
```

Comment: Why not change the function to return a value ?

Comment: Your method changes the state of the object after the observable returned by getUser() has emitted/errored, so that's what you test should check (if the code is correct). Currently, it checks that a local variable of the test method has changed, so that can't be correct. It also doesn't make the observable emit anything.

Comment: Is changing a function for easier testing a good practice? There is no use for it except for testing in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the service's properties directly if they are not private

```
it('testIfUserExistsIsFalse', () => {
  service.doesUserExist('falsegithubusername123');
  expect(service.searchedUserExists).toBeFalsy();
});
```

But really you should do as @auburg commented and change the function to return a boolean value, then you can test like:

```
it('testIfUserExistsIsFalse', () => {
  expect(service.doesUserExist('falsegithubusername123')).toBeFalsy();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If `this.searchedUserExists` is a public variable then check directly.

```
expect(service.searchedUserExists).toBeFalsy();
```